# How to show only message from log (hide time ,pid etc.) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, logcat

I haven't use Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA) before the logcat that show in Android Studio also show time and pid etc. on the left side of logcat. I want to hide those stuff (time and pid) I wanna see only message form Log.

Is there any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Please vote for this requested feature https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69879

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now on Android Studio you can config the logcat

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PID Cat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) from Jake Wharton.

```
pidcat.py com.health.main
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck on the same problem. As you pointed out this is a [missing feature](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69879), I hope that it will be added in the future.

For now, I've mitigated the problem by enabling the "**Use Soft Wraps**" option that allow multiline logging in order to avoid the horizontal scrolling.

[image]

**UPDATE**

As reported in the official issues tracker, there should be **more formatting options starting from Android Studio 1.4 beta 3**

> Good news, this should be out now with 1.4 beta 3 which we just
>   released today.

Answer (score 1):

Batter You can use monitor.
.
set the path in environment variable C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools; 
.
 and type monitor
.
and you can filter any type of messages however you want. :)