# Logcat in Run Tab

Tags: android, android-studio

It's a very basic question, I was getting Logs of information I create in code in `Run tab` after updating to `Android Studio 2.3` they are no longer appear in `run tab` only in `Android Monitor tab`

I don't want to search or filter all logs I just want to get those Logs back to the `Run Tab`, any ideas about that?

Thanks and sorry if this was stupid question

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574428/debug-console-doesnt-show-messages-after-upgrading-android-studio-to-2-3

Comment: Why can't you just use Android Monitor? That is the tool you should be using. The "Run" tab only shows you the `adb install` command AFAIK

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you for mentioning that question but it is not the same, I just want to see the adb state and the logs I wrote in code as the previous 2.2 Android Studio if it still be an option and is not deleted Android Studio

Comment: And you should see that in Android Monitor

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and i solved using `Android Monitor` tab, hiding time, process info and package name with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33255489). Now it shows equals `run tab`.

[image: See example]

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are seeing... I use pure IntelliJ IDEA, and it has (always?) been like this.

The Run tab is the Gradle logs.

[image]

And the Android monitor **is** where the Logcat exists.

[image]

Comment: thanks but I mean that in AS 2.2 it was displaying for example Log.i ("...", ".."); in Run tab, anyway I think it is no longer exist in AS 2.3, thank you again

Comment: Like I said, I haven't seen that window in a long time - even when AS 2.2 was still around.

Comment: I was using in AS 2.2 a couples of days before now before updating